# Finding data ending in ___ in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, sql-like

Trying to get get this information from a database: number of Zip codes where the city name ends in ‘boro’ or 'town' and has an average house value at or below $250,000.

This is what I put:

```
select count(*) 
from zip_codes 
where city like ’%boro’ and city like ‘%town’ and average_house_value <= 250000;
```

and keep getting this message: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%boro’ OR city like ‘%town’) and average_house_value <= 250000' at line 1

help?

Comment: I think you want (city like ‘%boro’ OR city like ‘%town’) and average_house_value <= 250000;

Comment: Which error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `where city like ’%boro’ and city like ‘%town’ and average_house_value <= 250000`

Issues with your query:

1. You should use standard single quotes instead of these funky `’` characters; likely, this is the reason why you are getting a syntax error
2. You want cities that end with `'boro'` *or* `'town'`, but you phrased a query that searches for cityes that end with both: this is guaranteed to return no rows, as no value can end with both strings at once

Consider:

```
select count(*) 
from zip_codes
where (city like '%boro' or city like '%tow') and average_house_value <= 250000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest regular expressions for this:

```
where city regexp '(boro|town)$' and
      average_house_value <= 250000;
```